# Assign value of a global variable in php from jquery file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an html file in which i have defined a global variable as

```
<?php
include("lib/db.class.php");
$db = new db();
$rings = $db->query("SELECT * FROM rings");
$mainRingId = 1;
?>
```

Now I have an Image

```
<li><input type="image" src="<?php echo $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath']?> " name="checked" value="<?php echo $ring['id']?>" data-my-info="<?php echo $ring['ringSetName']?>"  width="150" height="150" /></li>
```

In my jquery `jquery.ring.js`, i have defined its clicking as

```
$(document).on('click','input[type="image"]',function()
{
    $ringDesc = $(this).data('my-info');
    $('label#ringName').text($ringDesc);
    $ringId = $(this).val();
}
```

Now I want to assign this $ringId to $mainRingId defined in my html file. How can I do it. Further more if I want to do some processing in my html file how this can be achieved.

Comment: `var $mainRing = <?php $mainRingId; ?>` you can try this. Although i don't work on php that much but i see some people tend to do this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send data from user browser to your server you need to use AJAX calls. You can write AJAX calls in plain javascript, or you can use some existing library like jQuery, this example is taken from [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

POST values from AJAX call can be accessed in the PHP script by:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
```

In your case it will look a bit different, but the principle will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.. the only way would be to use a `$_SESSION` variable and set it by making a `$.post` or `$.get` ajax request to a file which will change the value of that variable.